# What is the difference between DOA5LR Core Fighters and the Demo/Trial on Xbox One?

Tags: dead-or-alive-5-last-round

Situation:

- I initially bought DOA5U on X360 and I received the update to DOA5LR. Not problems with that.
- I bought DLC characters and costumes on the X360.
- I just got an Xbox One and found that I can buy DOA5LR the full game and *DOA5LR Core Fighters* in the store, but *Core Fighters* is also available as a *demo*[?], so I tried that first (version 1.01A).
- The Xbox Store region is Europe.

Traditionally I associate a demo version of a game with some kind of expiration date or very limited functionality, but I don't see how functionality is limited, because playing online works in this demo.

I would like to use DLC I purchased on the X360 on the Xbox One. I already installed some costumes and characters, the character selection screen in the game however stays the same.

I tried searching the web for information about the differences between *Core Fighters* and the demo version, but I still don't have a clue what I will get from buying *Core Fighters* on the Xbox One. Will I be able to use DLC with it? Does it include additional content over the demo? I have the impression that it will be same and the no refund policy makes me hesitate trying it out.

---

In case someone wants to leave a comment like: *"Just buy the game if you want to play it!"* I did, I bought DOA5 and DOA5U for X360 and DOA5LR for PS4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the page on [DOA5LR Core Fighters](http://teamninja-studio.com/doa5/lastround/us/ftp.html)

> ## Fight for FREE* on PS4 and Xbox One!
>
> *Dead or Alive 5 Last Round Trial is a free download for Xbox One. Dead or Alive 5 Last Round  Core Fighters is a paid download for Xbox One.

Okay, that's a good start. The reason why you weren't able to find this information through your search engine may be because this information is from a static image with no alternate text and also the navigation on the site to individual DOA titles requires simple age verification.

Note the wording:

- Dead or Alive 5 Last Round Trial – the demo
- Dead or Alive 5 Last Round Core Fighters – the paid download

You may have somthing that reads different on your console, but I guess this is how it's intended to be. Let's continue with the features:

> - Add to your experience with in-game purchases!
> - Play all modes of the game (except Story Mode) as much as you want with the characters  included in Core Fighters without purchasing any
>   additional content!
> - Fight against other Core Fighters players as well as players with the full game!
> - Dead or Alive 5 Ultimate players can carry over their unlocked titles, costumes and story progress!

A table comparing different versions and platforms follows after that, which I won't include here.

You should have noticed in the trial version that not only the story mode isn't available, but also **there is no access from within the game to the store**. The menu option looks like this: <del>*Xbox Store*</del>. So while you are able to play online with the trial characters and you can install all already purchased DLC like characters and costumes, DLC characters will only become available once you *buy* Core Fighters or the full game. Note that costumes don't unlock characters, so costumes for characters that are not included in the paid version of Core Fighters and that you haven't already purchased as DLC will be unavailable. Consider that buying the full game may be cheaper than Core Fighters plus your favourite remaining characters at some point.

TL;DR: You cannot use your X360 DLC with the *trial* version you need the paid download version which will give you access to the store from within the game and a few more characters than the trial. Yep, I tested it myself.